# Android NDK - Error when building sqlite with ICU support

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, icu

I'm trying to build sqlite with ICU support on android NDK, in my Android.mk i have the following:

```
SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS := -I/home_folder/dev/platform_external_icu4c/common -I/home_folder/dev/platform_external_icu4c/i18n
```

But when i try to compile i got a bunch of `undefined reference` errors:

```
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuNext':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125631: undefined reference to `ubrk_current_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125632: undefined reference to `ubrk_next_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125640: undefined reference to `u_isspace_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125640: undefined reference to `u_isspace_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125660: undefined reference to `u_strToUTF8_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125639: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuClose':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125605: undefined reference to `ubrk_close_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuLikeCompare':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125075: undefined reference to `u_foldCase_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125076: undefined reference to `u_foldCase_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125052: undefined reference to `utf8_countTrailBytes_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuOpen':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125573: undefined reference to `u_foldCase_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125588: undefined reference to `ubrk_open_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125582: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125595: undefined reference to `ubrk_first_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125570: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuLikeFunc':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125126: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuCollationDel':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125312: undefined reference to `ucol_close_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuFunctionError':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125152: undefined reference to `u_errorName_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuLoadCollation':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125371: undefined reference to `ucol_open_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125382: undefined reference to `ucol_close_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuCollationColl':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125328: undefined reference to `ucol_strcoll_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuCaseFunc16':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125293: undefined reference to `u_strToUpper_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125295: undefined reference to `u_strToLower_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuRegexpFunc':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125216: undefined reference to `uregex_setText_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125223: undefined reference to `uregex_matches_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125234: undefined reference to `uregex_setText_46'
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125204: undefined reference to `uregex_open_46'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3_jni/sqlite3secure.o: In function `icuRegexpDelete':
/home_folder/workspace/ndk-sqlite/jni/sqlite3.c:125163: undefined reference to `uregex_close_46'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're post shows include directories, but are you linking in the actual ICU lib (.a) files such as libicuuc.a? They needs specified in your Application.mk via APP_MODULES if you have a .mk for ICU or directly via LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES (or even more directly via LOCAL_LDFLAGS).

The first method of APP_MODULES is preferred.

Comment: A version of ICU is installed on Android. A couple problems though: 1) You must rely on the version that's on any particular device and they vary, and 2) The built in data (conversions, etc.) that make ICU powerful also vary per device.

Comment: Do you know if a chart exists of ICU built-in data across devices? Sounds like it is risky to rely on. I need Break Iterators.

Comment: Sorry I do not. The only chart I know of by Google is http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html but it doesn't show what particular data is available. This is one of the main reasons we roll our own.

Comment: Did you run into the <typeinfo> issue?